# Need help with calculating the real and imaginary parts of the coefficients

Tags: complex-numbers

Can anyone explain to me how the solution to this question came about?

> Calculate the real and imaginary parts of the
> coefficients $a, b, $ and $ c$ in the formula $((4 + i) z - 2 + 3i) ((2 - 5i) z - 4 - 3i) = a ^2 z + bz + c$

**Solution:**

Re (a) = 13

Im (a) = 18

Re (b) = -2

Im (b) = 0

Re (c) = 17

Im (c) = -6

Any kind of help would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! [Try using the tips from this page to format your math to make it more readable](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/527653). Also, it's considered best while asking on MSE to also describe your own efforts to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you familiar with the basic operations on complex numbers? If so, merely multiplying through the initial expression and tidying it up to the general form $az^2+bz+c$ would immediately give you the required values.

Comment: Oh thank you very much, i get it now.

Comment: Great! If you figured it out, it's also encouraged to write up an answer yourself and post it.